# Scrape different pages using Scrapy

Tags: callback, scrapy

I've been trying to scrape different pages. First, I scrape a URL from the first page using the xpath(@href) at the parse function. And then I try to scrape the article at that URL, from the parse function request callback. But it doesn't work.

How can I solve this issue? Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from string import join
from article.items import ArticleItem

class ArticleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "article"
    allowed_domains = ["http://joongang.joins.com"]
    j_classifications = ['politics','money','society','culture']

    start_urls = ["http://news.joins.com/politics",
        "http://news.joins.com/society",
        "http://news.joins.com/money",]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = scrapy.Selector(response)
        urls = sel.xpath('//div[@class="bd"]/ul/li/strong[@class="headline mg"]')
        items = [] 
  
        for url in urls:
            item = ArticleItem()
            item['url'] = url.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['url'] = "http://news.joins.com"+join(item['url'])
            items.append(item['url'])
    
        for itm in items:
            yield scrapy.Request(itm,callback=self.parse2,meta={'item':item})

    def parse2(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        sel = scrapy.Selector(response)

        articles = sel.xpath('//div[@id="article_body"]')

        for article in articles:
            item['article'] = article.xpath('text()').extract()
            items.append(item['article'])
        return items
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a` print itm` after `for itm in items:` and checked if it returns valid urls ?

Comment: Result of 'print itm' was url(type of unicode) http://news.joins.com/article/18860833

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? Or is nothing being yield?

Comment: Did you define `items` in `parse2()`? Please re-indent your code correctly.

Comment: @Vaulstein nothing being yield...

Comment: At least the `allowed_domains` should be changed to `"joins.com/"`. In addition, indentations should be fixed in the `parse` function.

Comment: Glad your problem is solved.  Please up vote my comment if it is helpful.  It is how this community rewards good deeds.  Thanks!

Comment: hey @GHajba can you also answer my question please?
[here the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517655/scrapping-website-which-having-page)

Comment: What is `ArticleItem` and its code? can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you restrict the domains: `allowed_domains = ["http://joongang.joins.com"]`

If I change this to `allowed_domains = ["joins.com"]` I get results in `parse2` and article text is extracted -- as unicode but this is OK since the site is not written in latin characters.

And by the way: you can use `response.xpath()` instead of creating a selector over the `response` object. This requires some less code and makes it easier to code.

Comment: Oh! The restrict domains did problem. I really appreciate your help! ^^